Why does windows 10 calc need to click 3 times to open?
I found another post on this site that has the EXACT issue I have been having but it is closed with no solution. Here is a link to that original post Windows calculator launches only on the third try
Tldr: calc app, when opened with the calc button on keyboard, opens to just a blue screen with only the option to close, 2nd try does nothing, 3rd try opens like normal. If using multiple times in short period it works fine after that. If left unopened for a short period, same problem recurs. If I open it through the start menu or other way I have not noticed this issue. Since I use the calc many times during my work day this is very frustrating. I have reset the app, I have deleted and reinstalled the app, I power cycled the computer, I made sure all the windows updates were done. No other notes issues. Has been happening for a few months. If anyone has any ideas I'm all ears!

The simplest explanation, the application install is corrupt and needs to be reinstalled, which I recommended in the duplicate question.  The author just refused to implement that Do you have Windows 10 or Windows 11 installed?  You will want to [edit] your question to indicate what version of Windows you have installed, what the last cumulative update you have installed, and if performing a Reset on the application resolved the problem.

@Ramhound I disagree. They have the problem only when they use the calc button on their keyboard, but not if they open it normally. I would look into the keyboard drivers instead, or do something like pinning calc to the taskbar so it is just one click away there.

Workaround: The Win 10/11 calc is a Windows "app", not a traditional executable. It is balky. If you liked the old Windows 8 calculator executable, it can be installed: https://winaero.com/get-calculator-from-windows-8-and-windows-7-in-windows-10/

Also, if reinstalling the keyboard does not fix it, contact the keyboard manufacturer and report this as a bug.
